# How to replace with a capture of the first regex on intelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, ecmascript-6, replace

I would like to know if it was possible in "IntelliJ" to replace (CTRL + SHIFT + R) with the capture of the regex that allows to find the occurrences.

[image]

My regex: `\b(\w+)\s?:\s?+\1\b\s?[,}]`

I can't find myself any information about it.

My objective is to replace:

`model: model,`

by

`model,`

Thank you,
Jimmy.

Comment: If you want to replace the match with the first capturing group you might try `$1` in the replacement. To also keep the `,` or `}` at the end, try `\b(\w+)\s?:\s?+\1\b\s?([,}])` and replace with `$1$2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your pattern you are already referring to the first capturing group using a backreference and you could also use that in the replacement.

To keep the second part, one option is to use a second capturing group and in the replacement refer to those capturing groups using `$1$2`

```
\b(\w+)\s?:\s?+\1\b\s?([,}])
                      ^^^^^^
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QqwJzi/1)

Comment: I can use : `$1,` :)